# c# program freezes during read/write

Tags: c#, multithreading, freeze

I have a program written in C#, it does a lot of read from files from the disk and then output a few lines of text, not many possibly 100 at tops into a text files.

The program freezes about half way through, I'm new to c# and programming in general from research it seems that I need to use a separate thread from the one that controls the form. Two questions,

1. Should I used a new thread for the read and a new one for the write or just one for the read function?
2. What would be the best way of doing this?

I hope this makes sense and I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Is it a windows forms application or WPF?

Comment: This can also be done pretty easily using the threadqueue. Simply call EnqueueWorkerItem with the new read/write and it get's executed in time automatically. Though it might be overkill.

Comment: You have asked 7 questions on Stackoverflow but selected only one answer and zero up votes. Do select the answers and give up votes appropriately. If you didn't get the correct answer from anybody. Answer to your own question and select that as the answer. That would help others who come here to find solutions.

Answer (score 2):

BackgroundWorker is the best thing to use here. Here is a good [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) which describe all of its events and properties.

In brief this is what you should do.

1. Create a background worker instance and set appropriate [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker_properties%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) as you need.
2. Add all the I/O processing code to the [DoWork](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) which will be executed in a separate thread.
3. Add all the logics that you want to execute after processing I/O operation to the [RunWorkerCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) which will be executed in the main thread. Here you can update your UI or do what ever you want to do in the main thread. (You can access the result through the RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs.Result property)

The most important thing to keep in mind is both [ProgressChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) and [RunWorkerCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) events are executing in the main thread where you can update the UI by using the background worker results. Only the [DoWork](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) event executing in the Background thread.

Answer (score 0):

If the full read must occur before the write, you only need one thread - otherwise, you can use two.

Check this out for a threading example: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: and make sure you're calling Dispose() or "using" on objects that implement IDisposable.